# Compare mkv's creationtime

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server, windows-server-2016

I've been tasked with creating a script that checks to see if the office cameras we've set up have stopped uploading their feeds to the "Camera" share located on our Windows 2016 storage server. If the NEWEST .mkv is over an hour old compared to the current time (get-date) then the "problem" camera needs to be restarted manually. (No need to script that part.)

Here's what my Director has written so far:

```
#Variable Definitions start here

$numhours = 1

Get-ChildItem "d:\Shares\Cameras" | Foreach {    

$folderToLookAt =  ($_.FullName + "\*.mkv")
$result = Get-ChildItem -Recurse $folderToLookAt | Sort-Object CreationTime -Descending


echo $result[0].FullName
echo $result[0].CreationTime

}
```

The first variable really isn't used yet, but I'm kind of dumb-struck as what to do next. The above returns the full names and creation times successfully of the newest .mkvs

Suggestions on the next part?

Comment: Wow! thanks for all the suggestions Gents/Ladies. I'll be sure to post more in the future. Glad to see the community is super responsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your paths look like:

```
D:\Shares\Cameras\Camera1\file1.mkv
D:\Shares\Cameras\Camera1\file2.mkv
D:\Shares\Cameras\Camera2\file1.mkv
D:\Shares\Cameras\Camera2\file2.mkv
D:\Shares\Cameras\Camera3\file1.mkv
.
.
.
```

If so, I would do something like this:

```
# The path to your files
$CameraShareRoot = 'D:\Shares\Cameras';

# Number of Hours
$NumberOfHours = 1;

# Date and time of significance.  It's $NumberOfHours in the past.
$MinFileAge = (Get-Date).AddHours( - $NumberOfHours);

# Get all the folders at the camera share root
Get-ChildItem -Path $CameraShareRoot -Directory | ForEach-Object {
    # Get the most recently created file in each folder
    $_ | Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter '*.mkv' -File | Sort-Object -Property CreationTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
} | Where-Object {
    # Remove any files that were created after our datetime
    $_.CreationTime -lt $MinFileAge;
} | Select-Object -Property FullName, CreationTime
```

This will just output the full file name and creation time for stale cameras.

You could do something like this to email yourself a report when the results have any files:

```
# The path to your files
$CameraShareRoot = 'D:\Shares\Cameras';

# Number of Hours
$NumberOfHours = 1;

# Date and time of significance.  It's $NumberOfHours in the past.
$MinFileAge = (Get-Date).AddHours( - $NumberOfHours);

# Get all the folders at the camera share root, save the results to $StaleCameraFiles
$StaleCameraFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $CameraShareRoot -Directory | ForEach-Object {
    # Get the most recently created file in each folder
    $_ | Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter '*.mkv' -File | Sort-Object -Property CreationTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1;
} | Where-Object {
    # Remove any files that were created after our datetime
    $_.CreationTime -lt $MinFileAge;
}

# If there are any stale camera files
if ($StaleCameraFiles) {
    # Send an email
    $MailMessage = @{
        SmtpServer = 'mail.example.com';
        To = 'youremail@example.com';
        From = 'youremail@example.com';
        Subject = 'Stale Camera Files';
        Body = $StaleCameraFiles | Select-Object -Property FullName, CreationTime | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment | Out-String;
        BodyAsHtml = $true;
    }
    Send-MailMessage @MailMessage;
}
```

Generally you will want to use `LastWriteTime` instead of `CreationTime` since the latter can be updated by a file move or copy, but maybe that's what you want here.

Answer (score 1):

Invert the logic - instead of searching all the files, sorting them, finding the most recent, and checking the date, do it the other way round.

Look for files created since the cutoff, and alert if there were none found:

```
$cutOffTime = [datetime]::Now.AddHours(-1)

Get-ChildItem "d:\Shares\Cameras" | Foreach {    

    $folderToLookAt =  ($_.FullName + "\*.mkv")
    $result = Get-ChildItem -Recurse $folderToLookAt | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -gt $cuttoffTime }

    if (-not $result)
    {
        "$($_.Name) has no files since the cutoff time"
    }
}
```

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you so much! Now I just have to get an IF statement to e-mail using g-apps if there's a "No files since cutoff" incident. I think that's within my skill level. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You have to compare the `CreationTime` date with `(Get-Date).AddHours(-1)`. The `AddHours` method allows you to add hours to the DateTime, but also to subtract.

You can use the following example:

```
$Path = 'd:\Shares\Cameras'
$CreationTime = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter *.mkv | 
    Sort-Object -Property CreationTime -Descending | 
    Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty CreationTime
if ($CreationTime -lt (Get-Date).AddHours(-1)) {
    # your action here (restart, send mail, write output, ...)
}
```

It also optimizes your code a bit. ;)

Comment: It also doesn't do the same thing, the original code searches once per camera subdirectory, yours looks for one mkv file in the root directory

Comment: If that is a requirement, a wildcard can be added to `$Path`, like `d:\Shares\Cameras\*\ ` or `-Recurse` added to `Get-ChildItem`, depending on the scenario/folder structure

Answer (score 0):

```
$LatestFile = Get-ChildItem C:\Users\Connor\Desktop\ | Sort CreationTime | Select -Last 1
if ($LatestFile.CreationTime -gt (Get-Date).AddHours(-1)){
    #It's Currently Working
} else {
    #Do Other Stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
Get-ChildItem "c:\temp" -Filter *.mkv -File | sort CreationTime -Descending | 
    select -First 1 | where CreationTime -lt (Get-Date).AddHours(-1) |
        %{Write-Host "Alert !!" -ForegroundColor Red}
```